# Why do Non-American native bands have American names?

Tags: metal

For example: Amaranthe, Poets of the Fall, dEmotional, etc. They have American band names and songs (at least on their websites & youtube), but they primarily tour outside of the U.S.A., so why have American band names and songs at all? Just for the fan base to gain some extra popularity? But, they won't even come to the US... It doesn't seem to make sense, does it?

Also, if they have songs in their native tongue how do I access them?

For reference: https://www.metal-archives.com/lists

P.S. Not sure if this question is appropriate here, please move if needed

Comment: Uh... what makes those names American anyway? How do you know they're not Canadian, British, Irish, Manx, Australian, New Zealander, Dominican, Ghanan, Guyanan, Jamaican, Kenyan, Singaporean, Trinidadian, Israeli, or from some other country where English is widely spoken or an official language?

Comment: After I click on the theory tag it shows the description, "For questions about of how music works, seeking to identify structures and patterns in music.", which I am doing. I am trying to discover a structure or pattern in music. However, based off our conversation I assume that when the the description says "music" it means "sheet music", or something thereof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English is the language of today's troubadours, like Occitan had been in the middle ages.  It gives you a potential international audience and competition.  Many song texts, translated into native language, would be unfit for resonating with the native memes and culture.

There is some backlash in countries like France where radio stations are required to play a non-trivial amount of music in the native language.  But promoting this English language culture makes it easier for record labels to invest into superstars on international tours.

Also reverting to English allows for circumventing regionalism and be popular in regions with a different dialect of the native language (cf the German band "Scorpions").  As a corollary, quite a few popular singers in German "Volksmusik" aren't native German speakers, thus avoiding region lock-in.

Comment: Interesting that there's a need for there to even be a requirement to play a non-trivial amount of music in the native language. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that over time English has become one of the dominant languages in the world. With over one billion speakers of this language and America being one of the largest buying markets of songs, they will have to put their songs in English and band names in English names to gain popularity. I know of a few bands personally who went to America due to the fact that there is a large market for music there. But if a band can get the market without travelling, why would they?